# What's the significance of 1/cos(x) in this code for a 3d canvas game?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, 3d, geometry

I've been experimenting with HTML5 canvases lately and came across [this 3d example](http://www.benjoffe.com/code/demos/canvascape) with relatively little code behind it. I was hoping to find a good introduction to 3d rendering, but I'm having more trouble understanding the geometry behind the code than I was expecting to. [I set up a JSbin](http://jsbin.com/ifanod/1/edit) and copied over the code that was used on his website to play with. I'm stuck at understanding the meaning of

```
deltaX=1/Math.cos(theta);
```

which is later used in:

```
    if (deltaX>0) {

        stepX = 1;
        distX = (mapX + 1 - x) * deltaX;
    }
    else {
        stepX = -1;
        distX = (x - mapX) * (deltaX*=-1);      
    }
```

[Source](http://www.benjoffe.com/script/canvascape/main.js)

My best guess is that it's used for the relation `cos(x) = adjacent/hypotenuse` in a right triangle, but I don't understand where the triangle would fit in, if at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you draw a line from the origin `(0, 0)` with direction `theta` (measured from the x-axis), then

- `deltaX = 1/cos(theta)` is the distance on this line until the vertical line `x = 1` is met, and
- `deltaY = 1/sin(theta)` is the distance on this line until the horizontal line `y = 1` is met.

It is indeed a triangle relation. In the first case, the triangle has the points `(0, 0)`, `(1, 0)` and the point `(1, y)` where the line meets the vertical line `x=1`.

`(mapX, mapY)` is a grid point with integer coordinates, and `(x, y)` is a point in the square `[mapX, mapX+1) x [mapY, mapY+1)`.

`distX` computes the distance of the next vertical grid line in `theta`-direction, and `distY` the distance of the next horizontal grid line.

*Remark:* The computation fails if the direction is a multiple of π/2, i.e. the direction is exactly right, up, left, or down, because `sin(theta) = 0` or `cos(theta) = 0` in that case. This probably does not happen in your program, because the `playerDirection` starts with `0.4` and is incremented or decremented by `0.07`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I sort of saw this, but definitely needed to hear it from someone else. Much appreciated

Comment: Martin, you around? Might need a followup question.

Comment: @Walkerneo: Yes, but probably not for long.

Comment: Well, if you have time, I also don't understand `var wallH1=100/(wall[i+1]*fix1);`. Where did 100 come from? What use is the denominator?

Comment: @Walkerneo: I have no idea. To answer that, I probably would have to analyze the whole program.